# storing return value from function into pointer to char variable is rightway to do?

Tags: c++, c

I have written a read function which reads values from serial port(LINUX) . It returns values as pointer to char . I am calling this function in another function and storing it  again in  a variable as pointer to char . I occasionally got stack over flow problem  and not sure if this function is creating problem.
The sample is provided below. Please give some suggestions or criticism .

```
    char *ReadToSerialPort( )
    {
         const int buffer_size = 1024;
         char *buffer = (char *)malloc(buffer_size);
         char *bufptr = buffer;
         size_t iIn;
         int iMax = buffer+buffer_size-bufptr;

           if ( fd < 1 )
           {
            printf( "port is not open\n" );
           // return -1;
           }
           iIn = read( fd, bufptr, iMax-1 );
           if ( iIn < 0 )
           {
             if ( errno == EAGAIN )
             {
                printf( "The errror in READ" );
                return 0; // assume that command generated no response
             }
             else
                printf( "read error %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno) );
          }
         else
          {
           // *bufptr = '\0';
           bufptr[(int)iIn<iMax?iIn:iMax] = '\0';
           if(bufptr != buffer)
               return bufptr;
         }
        free(buffer);
       return 0;

} // end ReadAdrPort

int ParseFunction(void)
{
     // some other code
     char *sResult;

    if( ( sResult = ReadToSerialPort()) >= 0)
   {
      printf("Response is %s\n", sResult);

     // code to store char in string and put into db .
   }

}
```

Thanks and regards,
SamPrat

Comment: You should close the browser and your stackoverflow problem should go away.

Comment: Please fix your indentation, it is hard to read the way it is indented.

Comment: I've restored the c++ tag, according to the OP's comments, he is using `std::string` in the `ParseFunction` - please confirm with OP first before removing tags, causes confusion...

Answer (score 4):

You do not deallocate the buffer. You need to make `free` after you finished working with it.

```
char * getData()
{
    char *buf = (char *)malloc(255);
    // Fill buffer
    return buf;
}

void anotherFunc()
{
    char *data = getData();
    // Process data
    free(data);
}
```

In your case I think you should free the buffer after `printf`:

```
if( ( sResult = ReadToSerialPort()) >= 0)
{
   printf("Response is %s\n", sResult);

   // code to store char in string and put into db .

   free(sResult);
}
```

**UPDATE Static buffer**

Another option to use static buffers. It could increase performance a little bit, but `getData` method will be not a thread-safe.

```
char buff[1024];

char *getData()
{
    // Write data to buff
    return buff;
}

int main()
{
    char *data = getData();
    printf("%s", data);
}
```

**UPDATE Some notes about your code**

1. `int iMax = buffer+buffer_size-bufptr;` - iMax will always be 1024;
2. I do not see any idea of using `bufptr` since its value is the same as `buffer` and you do not change it anywhere in your function;
3. `iIn = read( fd, bufptr, buffer_size-1 );`
4. You can replace `bufptr[(int)iIn<iMax?iIn:iMax] = '\0';` with `bufptr[iIn] = '\0'`;
5. `if(bufptr != buffer)` is always `false` and this is why your pointer is incorrect and you always return 0;
6. Do not forget to free the buffer if `errno == EAGAIN` is true. Currently you just return 0 without `free(buffer)`.

Good luck ;)

Comment: Thanks Elafer,  Well intially I thought that I need to free allocated memory in the same function. but Its good to know your method. But unfortunatley , I have tried and still got invalid pointer error.

Comment: @samprat that's because you return buffptr, which is not the pointer returned by malloc() - you have to pass the same pointer as malloc returned to free(). It might also be because you don't check if the ReadToSerialPort() returns a NULL pointer, your  `if( ( sResult = ReadToSerialPort()) >= 0)` should be `f( ( sResult = ReadToSerialPort()) > 0)` , or better, check it for `!= NULL`

Comment: Thanks a lot  Elafer for explaining me all the points. You have cleared a lot of my doubts.

Comment: @nos, Thanks to you as well.  IT seem coding is running fine and I havnt got any stack overflow or segmentation fault. Need to run overnight for exact o/p.

Answer (score 1):

Elalfer is partially correct. You do free() your buffer, but not in every case.

For example, when you reach `if ( errno == EAGAIN )` and it evaluates to true, you `return` without doing `free` on your buffer.

The best would be to pass the buffer as a parameter and make it obvious that the user must free the buffer, outside the function. (this is what basically Elalfer sais in his edited answer).

Just realized this is a C question, I blame SO filtering for this :D sorry! Disregard the following, I'm leaving it so that comments still make sense.

The correct solution should use `std::vector<char>`, that way the destructor handles memory deallocation for you at the end of scope.

Comment: Hi Matias FG, could you please bit explain me further your stmt. Thanks

Comment: BTW the questions is tagged as `c`, no `c++`
Why not to use `std::string` then?
It could be not a good idea because of performance (of course it depends how to implement it)

Comment: Hi Matias FG, could you please bit explain me further your stmt. Thanks

Comment: once it store value in char variable , i am storing it into std::string and doing further coding with that

Comment: How would use use a std::vector<char> in C?

Comment: Sure, but I just realized that this is a C question... vector is C++. Anyway, your problem is that you are not freeing the buffer before every return, for example: when you reach ´if ( errno == EAGAIN )´ and it's true, the memory will never be freed.

Comment: Hi MatiasFG, I am using bot c/c++ code in whole file. so using vector is not prob provided it doesnt effect other code. Well about memory , I guess you are right. I wil investigate more

Comment: I edited the answer, if you can use C++ then the best would be to use std::vector<char>, if you are not familiar with it I would recommend to investigate about it, you can start here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/

Answer (score 0):

what is the purpose of the second pointer?

```
char *buffer = (char *)malloc(buffer_size);
char *bufptr = buffer;
```

what is the purpose of this?

```
int iMax = buffer+buffer_size-bufptr; // eh?
```

What is the purpose of this?

```
bufptr[(int)iIn<iMax?iIn:iMax] = '\0'; // so you pass in 1023 (iMax - 1), it reads 1023, you've effectively corrupted the last byte.
```

I would start over, consider using `std::vector<char>`, something like:

```
std::vector<char> buffer(1500); // default constructs 1500 chars

int iRead = read(fd, &buffer[0], 1500);

// resize the buffer if valid
if (iRead > 0)
  buffer.resize(iRead); // this logically trims the buffer so that the iterators begin/end are correct.

return buffer;
```

Then in your calling function, use the `vector<char>` and if you need a string, construct one from this: `std::string foo(vect.begin(), vect.end());` etc.

Comment: Again, this is `C` question, not about `C++`

Comment: @Elalfer, the "c++" tag was initially present, @Kleist removed that tag, the OP has not confirmed either way...

Comment: Thanks Nim, Iam tempted in using  using vector , but I guess then I have to change the hell lot of code . Well, I guess, if I havnt found any suitable solution , I may use your option.Thanks a lot

Comment: @samprat, if you want to continue to take your approach, you have to make it abundantly clear who is responsible for the memory that is allocated... with vector, you don't need to worry..

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting the null terminator "bufptr[(int)iIn

bufptr[iMax]=>bufptr[1024]=>one byte beyond your allocation since arrays start at 0.

Also int this case "int iMax = buffer+buffer_size-bufptr;" can be re-written as iMax = buffer_size.  It makes the code less readable.

Comment: use the code formatting, also, the check will always select `iIn` as `iIn` is limited to `iMax - 1`, but see my point about corrupting the last byte